# es6 Array Reduce function and string split usage

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use the array reduce function to return a 2D array of objects. The input is a comma separated values. The first row of the string is used as the title row. I'm analyzing the solution and I don't understand the notation. Specifically I don't understand the "=> ((obj[title] =
values[index]), obj), {})" portion in the code below. I'm looking to have someone explain it to me. For me it seems like we're initializing obj to be a an object. After that I'm lost.

```
const CSV_to_JSON = (data, delimiter = ',') => {
const titles = data.slice(0, data.indexOf('\n')).split(delimiter);
return data
  .slice(data.indexOf('\n') + 1)
  .split('\n')
  .map(v => {
    const values = v.split(delimiter);
    return titles.reduce(
      (obj, title, index) => ((obj[title] = values[index]), obj)
    , {});
  });
```

};

```
console.log(CSV_to_JSON('col1,col2\na,b\nc,d')); // [{'col1': 'a', 'col2': 'b'}, {'col1': 'c', 'col2': 'd'}];
console.log(CSV_to_JSON('col1;col2\na;b\nc;d', ';')); // [{'col1': a', 'col2': 'b'}, {'col1': 'c', 'col2': 'd'}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an (ab)use of the comma operator, which takes a list of comma-separated expressions, evaluates the first expression(s), discards them, and then the whole `(...)` resolves to the value of the final expression. It's usually something only to be done in automatic minification IMO, because the syntax looks confusing.

The `.reduce` there

```
return titles.reduce((obj, title, index) => ((obj[title] = 
 values[index]), obj), {});
```

is equivalent to

```
return titles.reduce((obj, title, index) => {
  obj[title] = values[index];
  return obj;
}, {});
```

which makes a lot more sense - it turns an array of titles (eg `['foo', 'bar']`) and an array of values (eg `['fooVal', 'barVal']`), and uses `.reduce` to transform those into a single object, `{ foo: 'fooVal', bar: 'barVal' }`.

The first argument to the `.reduce` callback is the accumulator's initial value (the second argument to `.reduce`), or the value that was returned on the last iteration - the code above passes `{}` as the initial value, assigns a property to the object, and returns the object on every iteration. `.reduce` *is* the usually the most appropriate method to use to turn an array into an object, but if you're more familiar with `forEach`, the code is equivalent to

```
const obj = {};
titles.forEach((title, index) => {
  obj[title] = values[index];
});
return obj;
```

While the comma operator can be useful when code-golfing, it's probably not something that should be used when trying to write good, readable code.

Comment: Thank you so much! when I asked on the coding site that I got the challenge from it told me to look at the documentation. After looking at the documentation I was still lost. Your explanation really cleared things up for me!